# Prove a consequence of the multivariable version of the inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

The exercise is the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that is class $C^{1}$ such that there exists $c >0$  such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \ge c|x-y|$$

for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

show that

1) $f$ is inyective

2)det $f'(x) \not= 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and

3)$f( \mathbb{R}^{n})= \mathbb{R}^{n}$ (Hint: consider the function $g(x) = |y - f(x)|^2$)

The first part I have it, but the second and third are the problem, I was trying to prove that  $f^{-1}$ is class  $C^{1}$  but I do not know how to do that with the hypotheses given. Can someone help me with this proof please :), I am asking because I dont have other ideas in mind that can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

2) A matrix $A$ is invertible **iff** there is some $r>0$ such that $\|Ax\| \ge r  \|x\|$ for all $x$.

Since $f$ is differentiable, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $\|h\| < \delta$ then $\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h \| \le {1 \over 2} c \|h\|$. Then
$\|Df(x)h\| + {1 \over 2} c \|h\| \ge \|f(x+h)-f(x)\|$. Now find a lower bound for
$\|Df(x)h\|$.

3) This uses the 2). Note that $\|f(x)-f(0)\| \ge c \|x\|$, so we have
$\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} \|f(x)\| = \infty$. Let $g$ be defined as above, then
notice that $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$. Hence $g$ has a minimum at some $\hat{x}$. You have
$Dg(\hat{x}) =0$. Now compute $Dg$ using the composition rule and use 2) to conclude that $f(\hat{x}) = y$.

Comment: I am back :), I am sorry for the delay :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21475/discussion-on-answer-by-copper-hat-prove-a-consequence-of-the-multivariable-vers).

Comment: @user162343: I will check chat around 1500 PST. If you want, you can email me. My email address is in my bio.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot copperhat I will be there :), at chat